Laravel Job not being dispatched
I have a very strange problem in Laravel.
I have an app which needs to send SMSs. It does so using a queued Job. This job has just stopped working!
To send the SMS, I call it like this:
SendSMS::dispatch("0710000000", "This is the text message");

There is nothing in the logs. Its not like its crashing, its more like its not being called at all.

The strange part is that all other jobs are still working.
Stranger still is that I can dispatch this job from other parts of the app and they work.
Even stranger still is in the function that is supposed to send the message it does some checks and either sends a failure SMS or a confirmation SMS. The failure SMS in this function works, but not the confirmation SMS (and as mentioned this has been working and the app is around 2 years old).

Also, if I change it to
SendSMS::dispatchNow(args here);

then it does work, but of course I don't want to lose the queueabilty.
I have tried restarting all services (nginx, php, supervisor) and the server itself. I've also tried clearing all caches, views, etc with artisan.

All I can suggest is try some logging. Log before and after the dispatch lines to make sure it's getting to that code. Add some logging in the constructor of SendSMS, and also where it sends the SMS. Maybe something is breaking down in the middle somewhere.
